# How can I implement x-frame-options in angular?

Tags: angularjs, x-frame-options, content-security-policy

Does anyone know why in localhost, `x-frame-options` appears in the browser console, but when I upload it for example to netlifly, the CSP and the `x-frame-option`, disappear?

Am I configuring something wrong?  Since my project does not have a back-end and the X-frame-options, I am configuring the angular.js with the following structure:

```json
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "headers" : {"Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only": "require-trusted-types-for 'script';",
            "Content-Security-Policy": "script-src-elem 'self'; style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' ;",
                         "X-Frame-Options": "deny
```

I did tests with CSP using meta tags in the `index.html`, but it does not work for me.  I used a meta tag to use `x-frame-ancestors` and I got a console error, that the `x-frame-ancestors` does not support it.